# Python, use a list of dictionaries returned from a function

Tags: python, function, csv, dictionary

I am trying to return the list of dictionaries and then use it outside the function:

```
 def myfunc():
     fileName: some file on my system
     with open(fileName) as csv1:
         dataDict = csv.DictReader(csv1, delimiter=',')

         return dataDict
```

But when I call t function, I get the error "ValueError: I/O operation on closed file."

```
myDict = myfunc()

for row in myDict:
    print(row)
```

How should I declare and use a list of dictionaries? Once the dictionary is returned, I need to also access its fieldnames. Any tips or help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just noticed I forgot to add the last two lines of my code which cause the error.

Comment: Not fair to say that what I say is not true ....... I am a beginner in this area .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `with` statement automatically closes the file.  When you try to access data through the DictReader outside of the `with` statement, the DictReader is unable to access the closed file, and so you get the IOError.

You can get around this by gathering the rows from the file into a list before returning from the function:

```python
 def myfunc():
     fileName: some file on my system
     with open(fileName) as csv1:
         dataDict = csv.DictReader(csv1, delimiter=',')
         list_of_dicts = list(datadict)
         return list_of_dicts
```

Comment: In this case, how will I access .fieldnames of the returned list?

Comment: You can't access the `fieldnames` attribute itself because, as you imply, you have a list now, not a `DictReader`.  But you could get the fieldnames from the first dict in the list:  `fieldnames = list_of_dicts[0].keys()`.  However this would fail if the list were empty.  For 100% certainty, you could return a tuple `(datadict.fieldnames, list_of_dicts)` from the function.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63539492/5320906) for a way to use the DictReader after closing the file.

Answer (score 1):

You could copy it into another variable and return that...

```
 def myfunc():
     fileName: some file on my system
     mydict = {}
     with open(fileName) as f: 
         for row in csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=','):
             mydict[row['first_column']] = row['second_column'] + row['third_column']

     return mydict
```

replace the column names with those in the csv.

Answer (score 1):

DictReader is lazy. Actually turn it into a list and return that, so that the file is read while it's still open.

```
def myfunc():
     fileName: some file on my system
     with open(fileName) as csv:
         return list(csv.DictReader(csv, delimiter=','))
```