# Why does the csv DictReader Dictionary object only work while the file is still open?

Tags: python, csv

I'm been learning python and playing around with dictionaries and .csv files and the csv module. It seems like the `csv.DictReader()` function can help turn .csv files into dictionary objects, but there's a bit of a quirk with the Reader objects that I'm confused about.

I've read a little bit into the documentation (and then tried to find answers looking up at the `csv.Reader()` function), but I'm still a little unsure.

Why does this code run as expected:

```
with open("cool_csv.csv") as cool_csv_file:
  cool_csv_text = cool_csv_file.read()

print(cool_csv_text)
```

and yet the following code returns a `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.`

```
with open("cool_csv.csv") as cool_csv_file:
  cool_csv_dict = csv.DictReader(cool_csv_file)

for row in cool_csv_dict:
  print(row["Cool Fact"])
```

Since we saved the `DictReader` object to a python variable, shouldn’t we be able to call the variable after we close the file, like if I were assigned `cool cool_csv.read()`?

I know the proper way to code this would be:

```
with open("cool_csv.csv") as cool_csv_file:
  cool_csv_dict = csv.DictReader(cool_csv_file)
  for row in cool_csv_dict:
    print(row["Cool Fact"])
```

But why does the `for row in cool_csv_dict:` section have to be nested in the `open()` section?

My only guess would be that because the `csv.DictReader()` object is not quite an actual dictionary (or something like that), there’s some shenanigans because it still needs to point somewhere (because maybe thats the "reader" part?).

Can anyone shed any light?

Comment: The `reader` just feeds on the file object that is given to it. It **doesn't** read the all the content at once. It just feeds on it, iterate over line by line and does the parsing, so the file object has to be open for it to read from

Answer (score 3):

`csv.DictReader` doesn't read the entire file into memory when you create the `cool_csv_dict` object. Each time you call it to get the next record from the CSV, it reads the next line from `cool_csv_file`. Therefore, it needs this to be kept open so it can read from it as needed.

The argument to `csv.DictReader` can be any iterator that returns lines. So if you don't want to keep the file open, you can call `readlines()` to get all the lines into a list, then pass that to `csv.DictReader`

```
with open("cool_csv.csv") as cool_csv_file:
    cool_csv_lines = cool_csv_file.readlines()
cool_csv_dict = csv.DictReader(cool_csv_lines)
for row in cool_csv_dict:
    print(row("Cool Fact")
```